# Cordova Contact Plugin save not updating new information

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

Im writing an Ionic app that uses the ionic-native contacts (based on cordova-plugin-contacts) to add and update contact information.

Adding a new contact (create) works perfectly, but once I try to save (update an existing user), it ignores part of my input (arrays?) and keeps the old after the save. My first guess was that there was an issue with the url and ims parameters but seems that this issue occurs with all arrays and not with string items.

How to reproduce:

```
let find = new ContactFindOptions()
find.filter = 0 // Some ID
let contact = await this.contacts.find(["id"], find)
contact.note = 'New note' // This works
contact.urls = [new ContactField("SomeValue", "http://www.example.com")] // This does not work
console.log(contact)
let result = await contact.save()
console.log(result)
```

Result will show the "updated" content and you will notice that urls is null while note was set. Same I noticed for emails. So it just ignores my input and keeps the old information for all array parameters.

Is this a bug in cordova contacts (Im using latest version and tried a version of a few releases ago too with same result) or am I doing something wrong?

I created a simple ionic test app that shows exactly which actions fail: https://github.com/Bramzor/ionic-native-contacts-tests

Comment: I noticed this problem too. What I did was just remove the old contact and created it as new with the updated/additional information.